# Is a TD rowspan supported in most browsers (including IE6)?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-6, html-table

I need to use a table row on my web page with a 'rowspan' set. I'm just concerned that some browsers may struggle with this. Are there any known issues? Or is it safe to use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`rowspan` (and it's partner `colspan`) has been around since before HTML 4. That translates to well over a decade. It's very well supported.

Answer (score 3):

rowspan and colspan have been around for ages... it's a standard html attribute, all browsers deal very well with it! :)

Go ahead and do your thing!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but colspan and rowspan are a bit unpredictable.

See: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/th/rowspan

Comment: `rowspan=0` seems to be counterintuitive anyway. What's wrong with just putting the right number in?

Comment: Reading my answer again, I can see that it reads as if the link explains the unpredictability part. I meant it as two unrelated statements. What I actually though of was that combining `rowspan` and `colspan` sometimes gives weird results. I think browsers are consistent about it, but it's still weird. Sorry - I don't have a good example at hand.

Comment: I believe that if it's well coded... with no td omitted by mistake, the browser performs 100% / 100% the table... but if the coder forgets about something, then, weird results appear :)

Answer (score 1):

`rowspan` has been part of tables ever since Netscape 1.1B1 introduced them in early 1995, so any implementation that ever fully supported tables will work OK with it. It has also been part of the HTML spec since 3.2 in 1996.